# Passing a function to module.exports in two different ways

Tags: javascript

I am working on a Discord bot and would like to have a js file with a few useful functions to use in all the other files. I'm using module.exports in the global.js file and requiring said file in the other ones for use.

I have found that if I do it one way it works but in another, which to my understanding should be the same  thing, does not.

This works:

```js
module.exports.commandMessage = async(message, commandArgs) => {
    message.reply(`This is a test, it should work, maybe. Who knows? I hope.\n ${commandArgs._}`)
        .then(msg => {
            msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
        })
        .catch(console.error)
}
```

This does not:

```js
const commandMessage = async(message, commandArgs) => {
    message.reply(`This is a test, it should work, maybe. Who knows? I hope.\n ${commandArgs._}`)
        .then(msg => {
            msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
        })
        .catch(console.error)
}

module.exports.functions = commandMessage // Hoping to make this an array of functions
```

It throws

```
TypeError: global.commandMessage is not a function
```

This is how I'm calling the function

```js
const global = require('../global.js')

module.exports = {
    aliases: ['test'],
    event: 'message'
}
module.exports.command = async(message, commandArgs) => {
    global.commandMessage(message, commandArgs) // or global.functions.commandMessage(...)
}
```

I know I can simply use the version that works and I will be doing that. This question is purely academic.

Comment: Have you tried calling `global.functions` ?

Comment: Oh, you're right. However, initially I tried with module.exports.functions = [ commandMessage ], intending for it to be an array.

Comment: I am still confused however. If I had something like `module.exports.functions = [
    commandOne,
    commandTwo
]`, I just tested and I can't call them with global.functions[commandOne](args)